# Generics in C# class in constructor?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# class with a constructor. The constructor currently requires a `logger<myObject>`. The code looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private ILogger<MyObject> _logger;

   public MyClass(ILogger<MyOjbect> logger)
   {
     _logger = logger; 
   }
}
```

I would like ILogger to take a generic, that way I can instantiate an instance of MyClass anywhere I want and pass in any type of `ILogger<T>` that I want, however, when I change `<MyObject>` to `<T>` I'm getting:

The type or namespace 'T' cannot be found. Are you missing a directive or assembly reference?

Meaning, I'd like the code to look like this:

```
public class MyClass
    {
       private ILogger<T> _logger;
    
       public MyClass(ILogger<T> logger)
       {
         _logger = logger; 
       }
    }
```

and to create it:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(ILogger<Something> logger);
```

Comment: It's always best to [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics) when learning a new part of the language.  Microsoft docs these days are pretty good.

Comment: You can never just use made up types. You always have to declare them. Where have you declared `T`?

Comment: When you post questions about generics, make sure that any non code mentions of <Something> in angle brackets are surrounded by backticks ` otherwise they get interpreted as html tags and disappear, making for quite confusing reading

Answer (score 6):

You need to do this

```
public class MyClass<T>
--------------------^^^
{
   private ILogger<T> _logger;

   public MyClass(ILogger<T> logger)
   {
     _logger = logger; 
   }
}
```

Comment: And maybe `ILogger<MyClass<T>>`